# Can we create a "Konakart" tag?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tag-creation, tags

Though it is a bit inactive as of yet, it might be nice to have a tag to group all ([at the moment ~25](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=konakart)) questions about [Konakart](http://www.konakart.com/).

I don't have the points needed to do this myself.

Overview: https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=konakart

Specific examples:

- [Konakart seamless login on Liferay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7349239/konakart-seamless-login-on-liferay)
- [KonaKart. Wrong character in database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13671847/konakart-wrong-character-in-database)
- [Could not instantiate the Payment module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14011727/could-not-instantiate-the-payment-module)

Comment: Can you post a link to example question, or to search results that will show them all? Just saying, might be easier to get some support that way ;)

Comment: Made the link more explicit.

Comment: [11 questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=konakart+is%3Aquestion) about Konakart...

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards: I don't think so, because here there already where questions, so we *can* add the tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just edited the tag into two relevant questions. [The rest](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=konakart%20is:q%20-%5Bkonakart%5D) can be done by anyone else.

Hint: earn some rep by suggesting the edits to add the tags (and don't forget to fix other problems in the posts as well).

Comment: I added it to the questions where relevant.